# Can't use a CSS located inside a JAR file in an JavaFX FXML scene

Tags: java, maven, javafx, javafx-css

When I open the following FXML file in IntelliJ:

```
<VBox alignment="CENTER" spacing="20.0" stylesheets="@/org/kordamp/bootstrapfx/bootstrapfx.css" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/19" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="com.example.demo2.HelloController">
    <padding>
        <Insets bottom="20.0" left="20.0" right="20.0" top="20.0" />
    </padding>
   
    <Label fx:id="welcomeText" />
    <Button onAction="#onHelloButtonClick" styleClass="alert-danger" text="Hello!" />
</VBox>
```

I get this error:

[image]

Note that in this project I have the BootstrapFX library defined as a dependency in Maven.

I'm assuming that stylesheets="@/org/kordamp/bootstrapfx/bootstrapfx.css" should look into the proper JAR dependency in my Maven external libraries and get the CSS file from there...

[image]

Of course, when I run the application from IntelliJ, it yields this error (the css is not found on the classpath):

```
Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException: Invalid resource: /org/kordamp/bootstrapfx/bootstrapfx.css not found on the classpath
```

So how can I specify in the stylesheets attribute of the FXML (or in my project's configuration) a path to a CSS file located inside a JAR file?

(I know that I can extract the css from the JAR file, copy it in my resources/ folder and include it in the FXML file specifying the relative path to my external css, and it works like a charm, but I would like to know how to do it directly from the JAR file)

Comment: There's a `module-info` descriptor, so my guess is that the resource is encapsulated, assuming the path is correct (it _seems_ correct). That said, [the example in the project's readme](https://github.com/kordamp/bootstrapfx) "installs" the stylesheet _in code_ using `scene.getStylesheets().add(BootstrapFX.bootstrapFXStylesheet());`. Perhaps you should try that approach (i.e., add the stylesheet in the controller) rather than trying to do it in FXML.

Comment: Indeed, adding the BootstrapFX CSS programmatically (following the README of the project), works as expected, but I would like to specify the CSS path in the FXML (Setting it in the FXML allows me to preview the styles directly in SceneBuilder -after adding the BootstrapFX JAR in the JAR/FXML manager of SB-)

Comment: Please don’t screenshot text, add the code as code formatted as text.

Comment: Thanks. As requested I added the code referenced in the screenshot but kept the screenshot because it shows the exact error in a popup; also it shows in red a possible error (that the CSS does not exist) and finally it also shows the "@" sign in green (meaning that it is syntactically correct to add that prefix). That "@" prefix is added by SceneBuilder whenever you reference an external CSS stylesheet in the FXML. Just in case I removed it, tried again and obtained the same results.

Comment: Does doing something like `<stylesheets><BootstrapFX fx:factory="bootstrapFXStylesheet"/></stylesheets>` work?

Comment: Wow! That did the trick! Thanks @Slaw! I didn't know that we could do that magic inside the <stylesheets> tag. Please, can you post it like an answer? I will gratefully accept it as the valid one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given it appears *BootstrapFX* is modularized, my guess is that the stylesheet is [encapsulated](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Module.html#getResourceAsStream(java.lang.String)). That means code from outside the library's module cannot access the resource, because the library does not declare the necessary `opens` directives. Though this should only take effect if *BootstrapFX* is being loaded as a named module (i.e., on the module-path). Otherwise, I would expect this to work:

```xml
<VBox stylehsheets="org/kordamp/bootstrapfx/bootstrapfx.css"/>
```

<sup>**Note:** In FXML, the `@` prefix is the ["location resolution operator"](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/19/javafx.fxml/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#location_resolution). It means to treat the subsequent path as being relative *to the current FXML file*. I doubt the stylesheet is located at `org/kordamp/bootstrapfx/bootstrapfx.css` relative to your FXML file.</sup>

That said, it looks like [the intended approach](https://github.com/kordamp/bootstrapfx#installing) is to use `BootstrapFX#bootstrapFXStylesheet()` in code. That method returns a string URL pointing to the stylesheet. The URL mechanism "bypasses" the encapsulation issue. That means you should consider adding the stylehsheet in the controller. For example:

```java
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import org.kordamp.bootstrapfx.BootstrapFX;

public class Controller {

    @FXML private VBox theVBox;

    @FXML
    private void initialize() {
         theVBox.getStylesheets().add(BootstrapFX.bootstrapFXStylesheet());
    }
}
```

However, it is possible to call the `bootstrapFXStylesheet()` method via FXML using [`fx:factory`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/19/javafx.fxml/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#instance_declaration_elements). For example:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>
<?import org.kordamp.bootstrapfx.BootstrapFX?>

<VBox xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml">
    <stylesheets>
        <BootstrapFX fx:factory="bootstrapFXStylesheet"/>
    </stylesheets>
</VBox>
```